# Query for Exam Score calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

**Problem Statement:**

I have an `EXAM` table which has following fields and sample data

```
student_id   exam_date   exam_score
-----------------------------------
  a1        2018-03-29    75
  a1        2018-04-25    89
  b2        2018-02-24    91
```

I want to write a SQL query to output the following fields

```
 1. student_id
 2. exam_date
 3. highest_score_to_date
 4. average_score_to_date
 5. highest_exam_score_ever
```

**My SQL Query:**

```
select
  a.student_id,
  b.exam_date,
  highest_exam_score_to_date,
  average_exam_score_to_date,
  highest_exam_score_ever
from
(
   select
     student_id,
     exam_date,
     max(score) as highest_exam_score_to_date,
     avg(score) as average_exam_score_to_date
  from exam
  group by
    student_id,
    exam_date
) a

left join

(
  select
     student_id,
     max(score) as highest_exam_score_ever
  from exam
  group by
     student_id
) b
on a.student_id = b.student_id
```

Can I achieve my result by writing a better SQL query?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, or MySQL? These are two different database products, please tag only the relevant one.

Comment: @GMB I was doing in MS SQL Server. I have edited my tags. thank you

Comment: None of your existing query has any relationship to "to date". Perhaps a minor issue and you may not even realize this mistake if your sample data is small and consistently "old". Often, when one refers to values as "to date" there is an assumption that a the information is relative to a selected point in time (i.e., one has the ability / option to generate this information for any particular date, not just "today"). OTOH - you don't actually define what your columns should represent beyond a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* indeed join the table with several aggregate subqueries that compute the relevant values at student and exam level.

But it seems simpler to use window functions:

```
select 
    t.*,
    max(exam) over(partition by student_id order by exam_date) highest_score_to_date,
    avg(exam) over(partition by student_id order by exam_date) average_score_to_date,
    max(exam) over(partition by student_id) highest_score_ever
from mytable t
```